# Django Get logged user in function in model

Tags: python, django, django-models

i have problem with getting access to user in function in model. Thanks for help,

my code:

```
class Module(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def ifended(self, request, user):
        return self.endedmodules_set.filter(user=user).exists()

class EndedModules(models.Model):
    uzytkownik = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    module = models.ForeignKey('Module')
```

Comment: Are request and user passed from view? If Yes You can get user from request ```request.user``` so You even don't have to pass user explicitly (as soon as It present in request).

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Set it in the view.