# Django: Define custom field in ListView

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I want to check if the currently logged in user liked a post.

Here are my models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    objects = models.Manager()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_pics', default='default.jpg')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    @property
    def useremail(self):
        return self.author.email

    @property
    def owner(self):
        return self.author

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    def get_like(self):
        liked = "False"
        User_id = request.user.id
        if self.like_set.filter(user=User_id):
            liked = "True"
        return liked


class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I tried setting it up in models (see 'get_like' function) however, as per [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872765/django-get-logged-user-in-function-in-model) it is not possible to do. How can I set it up in a view?

My view:

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 5
```

In html I have a loop

```
{% for post in posts %}
'html'
{% endfor%}
```

I would need to call something like this in html post.like_set.filter(user=request.user).first() however, if I put

```
{{ post.like_set.filter(user=request.user).first }}
```

in the for loop I receive a template syntax error:
"Could not parse the remainder: '(user=request.user).first' from 'post.like_set.filter(user=request.user).first'"

PS: Same thing happens even if I put 'user' instead of 'request.user'

Or maybe I can set up an API that would check this and have javascript code to call the API?

Comment: Maybe a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/) could solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you get_like function and pass the user.

```
def get_like(self, user):
    liked = False
    if self.like_set.filter(user=user):
        liked = True
    return liked
```

Write a template tag

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

def is_liked(obj, user)
    return obj.get_like(user)
```

In your template use

```
{{ post|is_liked:request.user }}
```

Remember to load you templatetag into your template

Comment: Modified the code as you advised but now I am receiving an TemplateSyntaxError at /
Invalid filter: 'is_liked' error after loading my page.

Comment: Added '@register.filter' before 'is_liked' function and it worked. Thanks!